# New at EntityFramework how do I write this query in linq to entity

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
SELECT i.answerc, d.answera, d.answerb
FROM tableone AS u 
INNER JOIN tabletwo AS i ON u.OneId = i.OneId
INNER JOIN tablethree   AS l ON u.TwoId = l.TwoId
INNER JOIN tablefour    AS k ON u.ThreeId = k.ThreeId
INNER JOIN tablefive    AS p ON u.fourId = p.fourId
INNER JOIN tablesix AS d ON u.fiveId = d.fiveId
WHERE u.columnone  = @parameter_one
AND l.columnone = @parameter_two
AND k.columnone = @parameter_three
AND p.columnone = @Parameter_four
```

I have the Model created, but how I would write this query is confusing me right now? Can anybody help me out here? I had this working using old school SqlConnection but I've been told to port it to the Entity Framework 4.

Comment: That's an...interesting...schema you have there

Comment: I am assuming those are scrubbed table names. I sure hope.

Comment: yes Scott they are, not sure what I am allowed or should make public so I did scrub everything

Comment: You need to include your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables are not in relations than there is no navigation properties in .edmx file. So your LINQ should be something like this :

```
var query = from u in context.tableone
    join i in context.tabletwo on u.OneId equals i.OneId  
    join l in context.tablethree on u.TwoId equals l.TwoId 
    join k in context.tablefour on u.ThreeId equals k.ThreeId 
    join p in context.tablefive on u.fourId equals p.fourId  
    join d in context.tablesix on u.fiveId equals d.fiveId
    where u.columnone == parameterONE 
      && l.columnone == parameterTWO
      && k.columnone == parameterTHREE
      && p.columnone == parameterFOUR
    select new { i.answerc, d.answera, d.answerb };
```

Where parameterXXX are variables.
But if you have navigation properties, you should use them!

Comment: I did use the Navigation properties, like Chris then you mentioned, it is the better more readable way. But, thanks for also answering the original question no matter how uninformed it was.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If  you're using an .edmx file, you can look at the designer and see what your navigation properties are. Instead of thinking in straight sql, think more in how you would build the object which you're trying to extract from the database based on your .edmx's navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks, I know it took me awhile, but I figured out what you were talking about with Navigation Properties. That is the correct way to go. I chose the other answer because he did answer my original question, but you and he were right. EF means not thinking in SQLness and joins. THanks for helping me get it right.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the relationships set up, I guess you can do something like this.

```
var query = from u in context.tableone
    where u.columnone == parameterONE 
      && u.tablethree.columnone == parameterTWO
      && u.tablefour.columnone == parameterTHREE
      && u.tablefive.columnone == parameterFOUR
    select new { u.tabletwo.answerc, u.tablesix.answera, u.tablesix.answerb };
```